# Rails How to calculate average of several select boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, average, drop-down-menu

I have 5 select boxes in my form.
User can use them to choose a note from 1 to 5.
I want to get these chosen notes from the selects 
punctuality = 5
attention   = 3
.
.
calculate the average and save it on the database.
Do I have to create a method in the model and access the params hash? or params hash is only available in controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access params in model. But usually params are accessed in controller. To solve your problem:

First, create a column to save average, I assume your table is called `grades`:

```
# generate migration file
rails g migration add_average_to_grades average:float
# update your database
rake db:migrate
```

Second, in your model calculate average with a callback:

```
before_save :set_average

def set_average
  self.average = [punctuality, attention ... ].sum / [punctuality, attention ...].size
end
```

Third, your controller should remain intact, something like:

```
def create
  @grade = Grade.new params[:grade]

  if @grade.save
    # handle success
  else
    # handle grade not saved
  end
end
```